# How to print the shell script terminal output in java

Tags: java, bash, shell

Hello I am trying to Run a shell script in java where the script contains sudo apt-get update and echo line, as shown here

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
echo "hello"
```

This is my java code,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String command = "/home/anon/Script.sh ";

        try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line + "\n");
                }

                reader.close();

            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

But this is only printing the echo statement and not the apt-get install or even asking password for sudo. Is there anyway to fix it? Please Help

Comment: How to read the log file dynamically? And also where would I enter the password for sudo? Sorry, new to java coding

Comment: `sudo` will read a password from the current terminal. You'd have to set up a PTY and duplex communication to it, which Java doesn't have standard APIs for (though you can run it through `script` instead which incidentally does set up a pty). I would not recommend this as a beginner's Java project. You can instead set up passwordless sudo and redirect stderr to stdout in the script so that your current Java program mostly works as-is.

Comment: Ok...I actually dont know how to do that either but this also brings another issue where if I am running someother tool which does not need sudo, like for example vi or nano does provide output then, how would I print that output

Comment: Since these are fullscreen TUIs and not line based tools, you can't read line by line. Read buffer by buffer directly from `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getErrorStream()` instead (unless you redirect them, you must read both concurrently to avoid deadlock). You'll get a bunch of ansi escapes that you'll either have to interpret yourself or feed to a terminal that supports them.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? Like an example or change to my code or something? Please